# Microsoft Band Cloud API Socket Timeouts

Tags: microsoft-band, socket-timeout-exception

In the last 3 weeks, we have been experiencing a huge number of socket timeouts from the Microsoft Band Cloud API.  When this issue started, a few retries were sufficient, however, at this point, it seems like it would be a never-ending retry loop.

We integrate with several other cloud API's and this is the only one that is experiencing this issue and is actually one of our lighter used API's, so I don't believe that it is load induced or our system.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?  Any recommendations?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that Microsoft Band was descontinued by Microsoft? This API is not stricted related to the Band, but in near future I don't use to develop nothing new

Answer (score 0):

The service was having some issues with it's DNS failover components, but should now be back up and running normally. Please let me know if it continues to happen.

Comment: Do you have a URL to reference regarding this?  How do you know this?

Comment: I'm on the dev team and have been investigating this. Still looking at a few other anomalies, but I think the worst of the issues should be resolved.

Comment: While the above fix did resolve the issue for a while, it seems to come back periodically including some right now.  Appreciate any insight.  Thanks.